# Setting transient boolean property while querying list from database?

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, criteria-api

I have two tables:

1- Device :
2- User: has foreign key to device, relation is ManyToOne.

i have list of devices and the device can be deleted if it's not assigned to a user
so i get all devices, and check if device is assigned to a user then set transient boolean property follows:

```
List <Device> devices = systemSettingsDao.getAllDevices();
            for (Device device : devices)
                device.setDeletable(!systemSettingsDao
                        .isDeviceUsedByUser(device.getId()));
```

i was wondering if there's more elegant way to set the boolean property with querying (criteria is preferable) without making this for loop ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how you could get all the deletable devices:

```
select distinct device from Device device where device.id not in (select u.device.id from User u)
```

You should be able to translate this with the Criteria API easily.

Comment: but i want to get all the devices the used and not used, and set the not used to be deleteable and the used to be not deletable, above code gets only the deletable devices.

Comment: Get all the deletable devices with the above query, mark them as deletable, then get all the devices, and this second collection will contain all the already-marked deletable devices. Or you could also join the first collection with the collection of non-deletable devices, which you could get using this simple query: `select distinct u.device from User u`.